# htaccess-rewriting, but excluding sub-directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a general rewrite-rule in my sites root which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/?([\w]+)? index.php?action=$1
```

which works fine for rewriting URLs like "www.example.com/myAction" to "www.example.com/index.php?action=myAction"

This must stay like this, but I need to exclude a subdirectory ("/login") from rewriting.

So I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/?([\w]+)? index.php?action=$1
```

but still no luck. I've read several answers here on SO but can't find the flaw. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've an extra slash. `.htaccess` doesn't use the preceding slash unlike a `Virtual Host`. Also `/login/` is a directory. So you're matching anything that is not a real file, but could potentially be a real directory. So if for instance '/css/' exists, you're rewriting it to index.php as an action on request.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^login/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?action=$1
```

If it's still acting unexpectedly you might need to make sure you're not rewriting existing directories and try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^login/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?action=$1
```

I also noticed that you're only capturing up to the first slash (possibly) with your posted example code since you're using the `?` look-up, so in my previous layout's I'm showing that code a little shorter. To capture the whole [URI](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) you would use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^login/
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?action=$1
```

To capture a second (and third) string you can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^login/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?action=$1&page=$2&response=$3
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, but you can alternatively try to have all requests for `/login/` be passed through instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login/? - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/?([\w]+)? index.php?action=$1
```